# GitFlow across 3 environments

Tags: git, git-flow

Ive got gitflow configured for my inherited repo and I’ve got three environments:

- Development (deployed to upon commit to the **develop** branch)
- Quality  (deployed to upon commit to the **master** branch)
- Production (deployed to from a CD tool but picks the latest commit from **master**)

We also use hotfixes to fix production issues.

As you may be able to deduce, during our Quality (testing period) we cannot actually hotfix as the Production environment and the Quality are both taken from the latest commit on **master**

1. I am wondering whether the following approach would work and be more true to git-flow?

   - Development (deployed to upon commit to the **develop** branch)
   - Quality  (deployed to upon commit to the **release/*** branch)
   - Production (deployed to upon commit to the **master** branch)
2. Assuming that, if the above would work, during the Quality (testing) period (i.e. after the start of a release), I need to make a hotfix, this wouldn’t be lost somehow - I am quite certain since this is committed onto the **develop** and **master** branch that it can’t be, but just double checking.
3. Also assuming that if 1. is workable - you are able to branch off the release branch for the purposes of code reviewing fixes to be merged into the release branch? We code review even the smallest of fixes.